# Upload file to Django backend by reading the file path from local machine

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I am new to django and trying to get below scenario working. Can someone please guide me?

1. Upload a master file which has absolute path of multiple files from my local machine or client machine which I want to process.
2. In Django template, within Javascript, I am trying to read each of the file location from my local system and upload it to Django backend server.

Is there any simple way to upload the file in Django by using the absolute path of a file from client machine?

Comment: I've read your question twice and it's really unclear what you are trying to achieve, especially step 1. Can you provide some examples or scenari ?

Comment: My understanding : step 1 -> upload a `path.txt` file to Django server containing *client* paths like /home/client/folder1 /home/client/folder2 

step 2 -> in JS, reading *client* files located in `path.txt` 

Am I right ?